# Bootstrap tabs feature not working

Tags: html

I'm trying to use Bootstrap's navigation tab feature, but I can't seem to get it working.

What am I doing (or not doing) wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Luis Gonzalez's portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="portstyle.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="navi">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Creations</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you'll need to reference the `bootstrap` files.

for now you can use these links:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Luis Gonzalez's portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="portstyle.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="navi">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Creations</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to download and host `Bootstrap` yourself, go to [`getbootstrap.com`](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/), and follow the instructions there.

If you don't want to download and host `Bootstrap` yourself, you can include it from a `CDN` (Content Delivery Network).

`MaxCDN` provides `CDN` support for `Bootstrap's`, `CSS` and `JavaScript`. Though you must also include `jQuery`:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**side note** - ensure that you link to your own stylesheet last, meaning **after** you've linked to all the `bootstrap` files. Otherwise, you might get some unexpected behaviours as in bootstrap `CSS` overriding your own `CSS` etc.